# Drawing to PDF create Blank white Page

Tags: autocad

using Auto Cad 2012 I am trying to export layout to PDF but I am getting white PDF! can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide more information if you want an answer.

Comment: Thanks but what kind of information? I have .dwg file in layout mode and I want to export as PDF? what else do u think I must say?

Comment: You could start by describing the steps you take to export the layout, including plot settings. Include sufficient detail so that someone else can reproduce your steps.

Comment: It would be appropriate, since you've clearly tried it, to provide some code that shows what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million (+-) reasons you might have this problem.
The information you provide narrows it down to 1/2 million.
Here is one of them:
Everything is on a layer that does not print.